# One table or many tables with relationships

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-performance

I have entity with 170 attributes. It's data from vehicle monitoring. Every entity has datatime label and unique id of gps terminal. Datetime and id of terminal - these are conditions for GROUP BY operations. I could create one table for all entity:

```
CREATE TABLE rows {
   terminal_id long reference terminals(id),
   time timestamp,
   -- description 170 attributes
   PRIMARY KEY(terminal_id, time)
}
```

or I could create many tables with relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE rows {
   row_id long PRIMARY KEY,
   terminal_id long  reference terminals(id),
   time timestamp -- need create index for group by
}

CREATE TABLE gps {
   row_id long references rows(row_id),
   -- description gps attributes
}

CREATE TABLE fuel {
   row_id long references rows(row_id),
   -- description fuel attributes
}
-- etc.
```

Please advise optimal structure for the database of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there would be no advantages in moving attributes to different tables, indeed you'd get worse performances due to the extra joins needed to fetch data from db. The decomposition you describe is only needed when modelling different entities that could exist independently from each other and this is not your case.